# Approach to serving documents only once to each user

Tags: search, indexing, full-text-search, search-engine

What would be the best approach to create a app where documents are showed to users only one, for example, Tinder.

Each person (i.e. document) is served to each user only once. After the user does an action on the other person (on the document), that document is not showed to the same user ever again.

What would be the best approach to build such a system?

- Store document IDs already seen and send them to filter them out to the search engine. This approach seems bad because you'll end up sending potentially thousands of IDs into the filter query to the search engine
- Store the IDs of users who have taken an action on the document, in a filed within the document and in the search query send the user ID requesting documents to be filtered out of said field. This approach can make a document's size grow a lot as potentially thousands of IDs are stored in a document.
- Create a index for each user with the necessary documents, and delete the documents from the index as the user takes action upon them. The drawback here is it's hard to maintain and update potentially thousands of indices.
- Store the viewed documents in the user object on a database, and query for documents. Once you get the results, make the controller skip or remove documents form the list that the user has already seen according to what the user object has stored. The drawback here is that you may eventually retrieve say 20 results, and all 20 have been seen by the user.

There must be a better way to build this type of application, which scales better.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have wondered this exact same thing as I am about to build a tinder-esque app. I believe the answer is that you simply request all users in descending order based on account creation date. If the database you are accessing has pagination , you will receive lets say 100 at a time. Then you have sort of a buffer area where you decide what you will actually show the user of your app and in what order. Once its been shown, you delete it locally. As long as you keep track of the date of the last user you got from the remote server, you can keep asking for more and never have to deal with repeats.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522248/how-to-avoid-calling-server-for-duplicate-data-using-using-google-maps-api   Check this as well